# samba: create mask & force create mode can't set group write bit

Tags: permissions, sharing, samba4

Tried all combinations for create mask and force create mode. Regardless of this, all created files got "rw-r--r--" instead of "rw-rw-???" (I don't care about "others" permissions).

smbd version 4.1.6-ubuntu (latest one from 14.04)

Here's excerpt from smb.conf

```
[global]
    workgroup = MYDOMAIN
    realm = MYDOMAIN.FQDN
    server string = Файловый сервер %h (%i:%a)
    security = ADS
    allow trusted domains = No
    map to guest = Bad User
    obey pam restrictions = Yes
    pam password change = Yes
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    unix password sync = Yes
    syslog = 0
    log file = /var/log/samba/%U.%m.log
    max log size = 1000
    load printers = No
    printcap name = /dev/null
    disable spoolss = Yes
    dns proxy = No
    usershare allow guests = Yes
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    winbind enum users = Yes
    winbind enum groups = Yes
    winbind refresh tickets = Yes
    recycle:keeptree = yes
    idmap config * : range = 10000-50000
    idmap config * : schema_mode = rid
    idmap config MYDOMAIN : default = yes
    idmap config MYDOMAIN : cache time = 180
    idmap config MYDOMAIN : backend = rid
    idmap config MYDOMAIN : range = 100000-500000
    idmap config MYDOMAIN : schema_mode = rid
    idmap config * : backend = rid
    valid users = @MYDOMAIN\\acl_rsk30srv042_valid, @MYDOMAIN\acl_rsk30srv042_sd-rw, MYDOMAIN\svc_scan_330-001, MYDOMAIN\sysop, eao\administrator, MYDOMAIN\svc_sadm_330-02
    admin users = MYDOMAIN\svc_scan_330-001, MYDOMAIN\svc_sadm_330-02
    create mask = 0775
    force create mode = 0770
    directory mask = 0775
    force directory mode = 0770
    map acl inherit = Yes
    map archive = No
    map readonly = no
    store dos attributes = Yes
    vfs objects = recycle, acl_xattr

[homes]
    comment = %S's personal folder
    path = /home/%D/%U
    valid users = @MYDOMAIN\xall-330
    read only = No
    create mask = 0700
    directory mask = 0700
    browseable = No
    volume = %U-%S
    vfs objects = recycle:keeptree=yes

[IPC$]
    path = /etc/samba/fakeIPC
    valid users = "@MYDOMAIN\domain users", @MYDOMAIN\xall-330, @MYDOMAIN\acl_share_330-sov2014, nobody
    guest ok = Yes

[obmen]
    comment = Common file exchange
    path = /var/samba/obmen
    write list = @MYDOMAIN\acl_rsk30srv042_valid
    force group = MYDOMAIN\xall-330
    read only = No
    force create mode = 0666
    force directory mode = 0666
    guest ok = Yes
    browseable = No
    volume = obmen
    vfs objects = extd_audit, recycle:keeptree=yes

[secret]
    comment = Depts' folders
    path = /var/samba/secret
    guest ok = Yes

[053]
    comment = 053 - IT dept
    path = /var/samba/secret/053
    valid users = @MYDOMAIN\acl_share_330-053-rw
    force group = @MYDOMAIN\acl_share_330-053-rw
    read only = No
    guest ok = Yes
    browseable = No
    vfs objects = recycle:keeptree=yes, extd_audit
```

Folder rights:

```
drwxrwxr-x   2 root root fakeIPC 
drwxrwxrwx   9 nobody MYDOMAIN\xall-330 obmen
dr-xrwxr-x  36 nobody MYDOMAIN\xall-330 secret
drwxrwxrwx 17 nobody MYDOMAIN\acl_share_330-053-rw 053
```

Tried from win7 box and from Ubuntu 14.04 - same results. Definitely, something wrong with samba4...
Tried to set

```
create mask = 0666
directory mask = 2775
force create mode = 774
force directory mode = 2774
```

newly created dir got permissions: drwxrwsr-x
but copied file still got: -rwxr-xr--

Don't know what to do... Boss forces me to move to winserver to avoid such situations...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SOLVED (seems to be)

The problem was in the **obey PAM restrictions** parameter. By default it is turned off, and I could not remember why I turned it on. The SAMBA config was partially taken from older installation may be I had reasons to be obeyant there :-)

When it is ON, then SAMBA-created files are under UMASK restrictions. I don't know, if it is correctable via login defaults (what is the user?), but umask command gives me "0022" which means "u+a g-w o-w".

Hope, it will help to someone with similar problem.

Comment: If you have solved the problem by yourself, please mark your answer as the answer to the question so others can be sure of the fact that the issue has been resolved.

Comment: Lifesaver:  Fixed my issue.  No mention of this effect in the samba cfg manual either. There are a lot of similar problems with incorrect misleading answers on stackexchange. Worth +10 not +1

Comment: After many fruitless experiments, this was finally the solution to get Samba permissions working as documented. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I searched a long time for this missbehaviour in my configuration. But still don't what the impact ist of setting it to no

Comment: Hope, it really helped... :-)