# Setting up a Samba server. New files are being created with no Write access to the group?

Tags: server, permissions, samba, users

I've been bonking my head against this for 2 days.  Maybe someone linuxier than me can see my error.

Ubuntu Server 22.04.3 LTS
Samba version 4.15.13-Ubuntu
Stand Alone Server

My goals:

- only allow authenticated users.
- all users are members of companygroup and can Read,Write,Execute all other users creations
- There may come a time when a directory or two needs to be locked down to a few users.

This seems like such a simple setup, yet I cannot get new files to have Write permissions for the group.  Therefore, other users can't edit.  Directories are working as expected.

All files end up with:

```
-rwxr-xr-x userthatcreatedfile companygroup ... test.txt
```

So user perms and other perms are good.  Write perms not there for group.

```
[DataMount]

path = /media/DataMount

browsable = yes

guest ok = no

read only = no

write list = @companygroup

force create mode = 0775

force directory mode = 2775
```

I have played with all kinds of settings for Force Create Mode and the settings will affect Read and Execute bits, but not the Write bit.

I added force user = rachel, which then allowed all the users to edit, but I don't think I can setup directories that only have certain people have access because they all are acting as rachel.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/574324/samba-create-mask-force-create-mode-cant-set-group-write-bit  explains it

Comment: That solved it!!  Thank you so much!

I had Obey PAM restrictions = yes.  Changed that to No and all is working!